# Execute plugin in a reactor pom before phase validate starts

Tags: maven-plugin

I want to write a plugin that retrieves the modules listed in the  section dynamically (by a file transfer) and then builds them in the normal way. I.e. the names of the modules are known at starting time, but the sources and the pom files are not yet available.

First I had the idea to run my plugin in the validate phase of the reactor pom before a check for the existence of the modules happens but this doesn't seem to be possible. The run (mvn validate) fails with the message that the child modules do not exist. :-(

So I can now implement a workaround with a wrapper script or something similar. But maybe someone has already solved the problem in a more elegant (maven style) way?

Many thanks
Rabe